# Delphi Data Snap Methods Class - Override Create Constructor

Tags: delphi, datasnap

**Important I am using Delphi XE 7**

I am new to data snap, and I have setup a data snap server and client with the wizard in the menu along side a short tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhHEqESQYUo)

The server and client application works and communicates with each other. But in my server methods unit (The unit that contains all the functions that the client can call) I am trying to initialize the variables that I have created in the class (Setting some integers to 0 etc).

I have attempted to override the `constructor create`, but it would appear as though it is never being called.
I have marked it with `virtual`, `override` and `overload` but none of them seems to be executing this code:

```
constructor TServerMethods1.create(AOwner: TComponent);
  begin
      messagedlg('worked', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
      inherited;
    end;
```

I originally had the variables in there but it occurred to me that it wasn't executing.
Am I missing something or does it never execute, and if it never executes how does the client call the methods.

**Edit - This is the class declaration:**

```
type
  tPlayer = record
    PlayerName: String;
    Spot: Integer;
  end;

{$METHODINFO ON}

  TServerMethods1 = class(TComponent)

    TmrGameStarted: TTimer;
  private
    { Private declarations }

    fSpot1Taken: Boolean;
    fSpot2Taken: Boolean;
    fSpot3Taken: Boolean;
    fSpot4Taken: Boolean;
    fSpot5Taken: Boolean;

    Player: Array [1 .. 5] of tPlayer;

    fGameStarted: Boolean;

  public
    { Public declarations }

    fPlayerCount: Integer;

    constructor create(AOwner: TComponent); overload;

    function getPlayerCount: Integer;
    procedure setPlayerCount(i: Integer);
    function EchoString(Value: string): string;
    function ReverseString(Value: string): string;
    function Attempt_Join(sPlayerName: String; sPassword: String): String;
    function UpdateLog: String;
    function GameStarted: String;

  end;
{$METHODINFO OFF}
```

I have also included the following in my `constructor`:

```
constructor TServerMethods1.create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  messagedlg('worked', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
  inherited create(AOwner);
end;
```

This is the `constructor` method from `System.Classes` which is a public declaration `constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); virtual;`

```
{ TComponent }

constructor TComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FComponentStyle := [csInheritable];
  if AOwner <> nil then AOwner.InsertComponent(Self);
end;
```

This is also added in the type declaration but I have no idea what it does

```
private class var
    FComparer: IComparer<TComponent>;
    class constructor Create;
```

Constructor method:

```
class constructor TComponent.Create;
begin
  FComparer := TDelegatedComparer<TComponent>.Create(
    function(const Item1, Item2: TComponent): Integer
    begin
      Result := CompareText(Item1.Name, Item2.Name);
    end);
end;
```

Comment: Show the declaration of the type, and where you wrote `override`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I've added the types from my unit. I have also replaced `overload` with `override` as well as `virtual` in a hope that it will execute my create statement as opposed to the one in the original TComponent class. (I will post the original constructor in the original question now)

Comment: You really need to stop using trial and error. It has to be `override`. You do need to understand why that is so.

Comment: As David said, change the overload directive to **override**. This will override the ancestor's Create and allow you to add things to the constructor sequence. I am interested in something else though; show us the code where you create an instance of TServerMethods1. Also why derive from TComponent when there are other classes you can derive from; something like TPersistent?

Comment: ...Most times TComponent derived classes are things that generally, but not always are used for non-visual components that you can place on forms if you made it a design-time component for example: TTimer, TidTCPClient, TPopupMenu, etc. If you want an object which does certain custom things without needing much from its ancestor then it usually is a good idea to derive from a class as simple as possible with not too many bells and wistles. TPersistent is a cool little object.

Comment: I know the Delphi help confuses some people but you can go to http://www.delphibasics.co.uk and search for things like override, virtual, constructor and Create. It usually gives nice explanations and examples.

Comment: @BlurrySterk as I said before I am new to using data snap, and I wanted an alternative than using a web server such as Apache - PHP or VB - IIS.

It automatically created all the classes for me, I just added my own additional functions after the wizard was finished

Comment: As David and Blurry Sterk said, change the overload directive to override. I guess it has to do with your understanding of LifeCycle property of TDSServerClass on ServerContainer. Default value is Session which means every client has it's own instance of TServerMethods1 class. Set LifeCycle property to Server and then different clients share same instance of TServerMethods1 class: it is now initialized by other clients and I guess this is what you want. Pawel Glowacki has nice set of tutorials on DataSnap http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/delphi-labs

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I have found the answer to my question. The on create even fires **but it fires each time the client calls the function**.

After doing some more research it would appear as there isn't an actual way to manipulate the server methods from a form or an application.

Datasnap could be useful depending on what you need it for, In my case I used it in the incorrect way. To use the create constructor just add the override directive. This will override the default parent constructor and execute yours.